# Getting "Temporary failure in name resolution" when running pip as a Dockerfile stage

Tags: docker, pip, dns, debian

I'm trying to do docker compose a project of mine and run it on my home server. The server runs Debian 11. As part of my Dockerfile that the compose file calls, I do `pip install -r requirements.txt`, which gives me this error:

```
#0 21.27 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7efff0d95750>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/asgiref/
#0 41.79 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7efff0ca6190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/asgiref/
#0 62.82 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7efff0cbd9d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/asgiref/
#0 84.84 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7efff0d95b90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/asgiref/
#0 108.9 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7efff0d96410>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/asgiref/
#0 128.9 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement asgiref==3.5.2 (from versions: none)
#0 128.9 ERROR: No matching distribution found for asgiref==3.5.2
```

On the same server I run a Pihole instance, and my server is set up to use this as its nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`. I suspect this might have something to do with it, but I have no problem pinging any website or doing the pip install manually on the same machine. Any thoughts on what could be the problem?

**Edit:** Simply changing my `/etc/resolv.conf` to contain `nameserver 127.0.0.1` solved the issue of not being able to install pip packages with docker, but it doesn't explain why. As said before doing `pip install` outside the container did not pose any problems, so using Pihole as the DNS should not be a problem. No urls have been blocked by the Pihole from the server either.